# Why is my DLookup producing "invalid use of null" Error: 94

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

In my Access VBA code, I have several `DLOOKUP` functions in a sequence. They are all the same except for the value the parameter they are returning from 'studys'.

The last one is occasionally producing the error:

> invalid use of null

The line of code producing the error is:

```vb
 necropsy = DLookup("[Necropsy]", "Studys", "[Primary Key] = " & ID)
```

The necropsy value in Study's is a null Date occasionally but that is why I am looking it up.

In comparison the line above it:

```vb
studyEnd = DLookup("[Study End]", "Studys", "[Primary Key] = " & ID)
```

This code runs fine. It would never return a null value as study end is never null.

What's up?

Comment: Yes, awesome. I thought you had to be explosive about var declarations in vba.

Comment: you could keep it as a date and wrap the `DLookup` in a `NZ` function.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `Dim necropsy As Date`, `necropsy` can not accept Null because Null is not a Date/Time value.

If you want to allow `necropsy` to accept Null, make it a Variant instead: `Dim necropsy As Variant`

Answer (score 1):

A date cannot be Null in VBA.

If you simply remove the variable declaration it will be returned as a date when not null.

Comment: If the module's Declarations include `Option Explicit`, removing the variable declaration will cause a compile error.  In that case, declare it `As Variant` so it can accept Null.  (You should always include `Option Explicit` in your code modules.)